# How to debug grpc calls between pods_

Tags: go, kubernetes, grpc

I have two pods interact with each other using grpc, how to debug grpc calls between those two pods?

I already try to set:

```
export GRPC_TRACE=all
export GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG
```

then using `kubectl logs <pod> -n namespces` does not show up any grpc logs, how to debug grpc between pods?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to debug: If you just want to know if there are communications on the Network, then you will have to add something outside of your 2 programs.

If you are the developer of these programs, you can add middlewares to the gRPC clients/servers to add trace (e.g, using OpenTelemetry tracing and Jaeger) to get cross-services traces (you can propagate traces IDs on the network).

Otherwise, without knowing what your programs are we can't help you only with environment variables.